# Placeholder issue

Tags: c, printf, placeholder, cs50

I wanted to use a placeholder for the int `age`, but %i or %s are not working.

This is my code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int age = get_int("What is your age ?\n");
    printf("You are %i years old.\n");
}
```

This is the error :

```
test1.c:7:22: error: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("You are %i years old.\n");
                    ~^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'test1' failed
make: *** [test1] Error 1
```

Comment: `printf("You are %i years old.\n", age);`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Please turn that into an explained answer.

Comment: In `printf()` and family, each `%` argument in the formatting string needs a corresponding additional argument to be passed, with the data for that format specification. If missing (as here) some compilers will treat that as an error, some may warn, and some ignore (also depending on settings). The executable C code is unforgiving in that respect: no compiler is *required* to tell you, and the code will try to do what it was told, mistake or not.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass `age` to `printf`:

```c
 printf("You are %i years old.\n", age);
/* Here ---------------------------^ */
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which variable you want to print for each "%i" you use.
Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int x = 9;
    int y = 10;
    printf("x = %i, y = %i", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also use %d for int numbers. %s is used for strings.